# Java getting text of button inside a for

Tags: java, swing, onclick, jframe, jbutton

What i need to make to when i click in button, he give me the text inside of the button? Because in this code, if i click button return me ever the last "i" var value... In this case he giving to me "5".

```
for(int i; i < 5; i++) {
      JButton button = new JButton();
      button.setText("" + i);
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { 
           // TODO add your handling code here:
           System.out.print("\n Test: " + button.getText());

         } 
      });
      button.setSize(60,20);
      button.setLocation(100, 140);
      button.setVisible(true);
      this.add(button);
      this.revalidate();
      this.repaint();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
System.out.print("\n Test: " + button.getText());
```

to

```
System.out.print("\n Test: " + ae.getActionCommand());
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not post the original code. As posted it would not compile, so I think `button` is a field in your class.

The posted code would work with a small modification:

```
for (int i; i < 5; i++) {
    // Notice the "final"
    final JButton button = new JButton();
    ...
```

You should likely do this even if you follow Hovercraft's good advice of getting the string from the action event, because the `button` field is useless.

Getting the string from the action event, you can also reuse one listener for all the buttons:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { 
      System.out.print("\n Test: " + ae.getActionCommand());
    } 
};

for (int i; i < 5; i++) {
    final JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText(Integer.toString(i));
    button.addActionListener(listener);
    // the rest as before
    ...
}
```

Comment: i didnt put the original source, i just put an example to know the logic... :))..